# How to check in Apex if a user has sharings to a given record?

Tags: apex, soql, sharing, sharing-rule, apex-sharing

I have an ID of a user (let's say 'id_1111111111') and I have an ID ('id_2222222222') of a record of a custom object Job__c.

How can I check in Apex / SOQL if the user with id 'id_1111111111' has sharings to a record with 'id_2222222222'?

I checked Apex documentation but I didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) object.

```
SELECT RecordId,
    MaxAccessLevel
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId = 'id_1111111111'
AND RecordId = 'id_2222222222'
```

Valid values are:

- None
- Read
- Edit
- Delete
- Transfer
- All

You can add one or more of these values to check specific access to the record from the user or can perform conditional checks after the SOQL has completed.